# Русская Православная Церковь за()границей

Tags: орфография

Русская Православная Церковь заграницей.

В официальном названии "заграницей", если не путаю, слитно.

Хотелось бы знать, почему.

Что это, правило, традиция, исторический казус или просто некоторый узаконенный орфографический нигилизм?

С заглавной в "Церковь" тоже не всё ясно, но с этим я уже смирился.

Comment: Это традиция. До 1918, если не до 1954 г. подобное написание имело право на существование. Подробнее, может, потом напишу. Хотя можете гуглом воспользоваться, в сети есть кое-что на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

Прошла по ссылке Sibyllы. Там в рамочке  заметили?

***Текущая версия страницы пока не проверялась опытными участниками и может значительно отличаться от версии, проверенной 6 апреля 2016; проверки требуют 5 правок.**
External.svg
Эту страницу предлагается переименовать в **Русская православная церковь за границей.**
Пояснение причин и обсуждение — на странице Википедия: К переименованию/6 апреля 2016.
Возможно, её текущее название не соответствует нормам современного русского языка и/или правилам именования статей Википедии.
Не снимайте пометку о выставлении на переименование до окончания обсуждения.
Дата постановки — 6 апреля 2016.*

**Так что там уже идёт обсуждение, грамотное ли написание. Видимо, кто-то увидел ошибку, как и Вы. А это именно ошибка.**

Варианты правильного написания "заграницу" и “за границу” зависят от используемого контекста.

1. Итак,  есть сущ. “граница”, если к нему добавить предлог и задать вопрос  ”где”, получим: за границей.  Находится за границей нашей Родины. За границей я впервые попробовала экзотические фрукты .  Я купил путевку и скоро уезжаю за границу.

Если отвечает на вопросы “где”, “куда”, “откуда” и является обстоятельством в предложении, то пишем раздельно. Где ты был? Я был за границей. Я еду (куда?) за границу.Ты откуда?- Из-за границы.

2. Есть сущ. “заграница”, которое чаще всего является дополнением в предложениии, отвечая на вопрос (что?).

   Если отвечает на вопросы  ”чем”, “что” и является дополнением в предложении, то пишем  “заграница” слитно.
   Пример: Я помню заграницу давних лет, я стою в России и вижу заграницу.  “….заграница нам поможет…”.Он сидит на балконе и любуется заграницей. Недоволен заграницей.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Только я знаю, что слово "заграница" само по себе возможно, меня интересует конкретный случай и причины выбора. А про Википедию - ну там нет ничего интересного, уровень аргументации - ниже всякой критики.  Да и не интересует меня, как там будет статья называться, это вообще не моего ума дела. Мне хочется понять, как такое могло возникнуть.

Comment: И да, я отнюдь не считаю ошибкой такое написание, имя собственное не всегда подчиняется общим правилам. Это не ошибка, это прецедент.

Answer (score 0):

Из Википедии

Возможно, её текущее название не соответствует нормам современного русского языка.

[Русская православная церковь заграницей | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Можно предположить, что это заурядная орфографическая ошибка, неверное толкование значения слова.

ЗАГРАНИЦА, -ы; ж. Разг. собир. З**арубежные страны, иностранные государства.** Торговые связи с заграницей. Надеяться на помощь заграницы. Тосковать по загранице. Пресмыкаться, преклоняться перед заграницей. Всю жизнь прокатался по заграницам.

Но: жить за границей, уехать за границу

ГРАНИЦА, **Условная линия раздела** между территориями; рубеж.

Comment: Нет, 1) Если это и орфографическая ошибка, то не заурядная ошибка, ибо "заурядную" в названии давно бы поправили.  2) Церкви этой под сто лет,  у её истоков, поверьте, стояли совсем  не безгамотные люди, с высшем классическим и богословским образованием. ----- И наконец, словарь Кузнецова, как тут кто-то уже говорил, толковый, как источник ***орфографической** нормативности мало кем признаётся.

Comment: "На территории России и Украины существуют общины Русской Православной Церкви Заграницей". (Всё с прописной буквы). Возможно, условное или традиционное  название, но нормам современного языка никак не соответствующее. За границей (наречное выражение с раздельным написанием) - за пределами страны. Какой смысл в наречии "заграницей" с тем же значением? Есть существительное заграница и форма Т.п. для этого существительного: связи с заграницей, страны Средней Азии стали для России заграницей. Если  это особая орфография или особое значение, то здесь только образованные богословы разберутся.

Comment: Кстати, по поводу  написания всех слов с прописной буквы, в этом случае менять форму написания будет неудобно (не писать же предлог с прописной буквы): Русская Православная Церковь За Границей.

Answer (score 0):

Я все-таки собрался бросить свои пять копеек. 
Вы совершенно верно ставите вопрос о "собственном имени", хотя это и не собственное имя в чистом виде. Это название, закрепленное в своего рода учредительных документах. Т. е. ставить вопрос о **неправильности** - некорректно, это все равно, что Пушкина править, например, в написании имени "Германн" на том основании, что имя пишется с одной Н. Или Ё проставлять там, где это противоречит рифме (Исчез властитель осужденный, // Могучий баловень побед, // И для изгнанника вселенной // Уже потомство настает). Другими словами - это авторское написание, название учреждения должно соответствовать зарегистрированному.

Предвижу возражения насчет ятя, ера и прочего. Упреждая, отвечу. Да, в тех случаях, когда подобное прямо следует из нормативных документов, такое изменение орфографии не только возможно, но и необходимо. Но только в рамках предусмотренного реформой и уточнениями.

Таким образом, в любом случае это не ошибка, а освященная временем традиция, и попытки навязать иное написание - вандализм.

Вот как и почему дошли они до жизни такой - это вопрос спорный. Насколько понимаю, все довольно заурядно. Церковная орфография (да и вообще правописание) всегда было немного фрондой по отношению к общелитературному, официальному. И там подобное встречается достаточно часто. Бороться за единообразие - такую задачу себе не ставила ни та, ни другая сторона, эти две системы мирно сосуществовали в разных сферах письменного языка. Большевики немного "подвинули" церковников на место, но сейчас это отношение стало отчасти возрождаться, правда в основном это пока касается заглавных букв во всякого рода праздниках, названиях, именах и прочих символах. Но не только. Это отдельная тема, не буду здесь перегружать.

А вывод такой. Я считаю это традицией и надеюсь на уважение к ней. Пусть даже и отношение к этой ветви русского православия у официальных структур весьма неоднозначное.